# Missing Jupyter Notebook Kernels in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have multiple people working on the same AWS EMR cluster to run some Spark jobs.  This is being done through Jupyter Notebooks which are created/modified using the Jupyter extension installed on a SSH Target through vscode.  The modules are installed on the base conda environment that is included with the /emr/notebook-env/.  Some people can see the correct kernel that is associated with the base conda environment in their vscode window when working on notebooks.  However, some don't see this kernel as an option.  How do I make sure that everyone's vscode lists the appropriate kernel when they are creating new notebooks or modifying existing notebooks?

Answer (score 2):

Another potential reason this could happen is that the [Jupyter exentsion of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter) is not installed.

To add the Jupyter extension for VSCode, search for it by clicking extensions icon in lefthand toolbar, then searching for Jupyter and installing.

Answer (score 1):

The user having the issue had to update their vscode and that fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the automatic update of the Jupiter extension making it incompatible with the VScode de version I was using.

Luckily there was an option to downgrade to previous versions of the extension.